# Perfect of modal "to have to" in infinitive-clause

Tags: present-perfect

Take the following sentence:

> I claim to have had to have done something.

As I understand it, it means that I was obliged at some point to have done/finished something at that time.

- Is that sentence grammatically correct?
- Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: A more specific example sentence would help. Are you asking about a sentence like *"I claim to have had to have bought the plane tickets before I could apply for a Ruritanian visa"*? You probably wouldn't say that even if you used *"was obliged"*; you'd say *"I claim to have been obliged to buy the plane tickets before I could apply for a Ruritanian visa."* But if you're just asking about the construction *"to have had to"*, there's nothing wrong with it;  the sentence *"I claim to have had to buy the plane tickets before I could apply for a Ruritanian visa."* sounds fine to me.

Comment: @PeterShor... thanks so far. It doesn't really matter in my case whether it is idiomatic or not. What I want to know is if it is technically correct. The context you suggested works fine. So... is it grammatical ?

Comment: It sounds very awkward to me, but I don't see any reason that it's not grammatically correct.

Comment: @PeterShor... if you were to make your comments into an answer I'd gladly accept it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking about a sentence like this?

> I claim to have had to have bought the plane tickets before I could apply for a Ruritanian visa.

You probably wouldn't say that even if you used "was obliged"; you'd say:

> I claim to have been obliged to buy the plane tickets before I could apply for a Ruritanian visa.

But if you're just asking about the construction "to have had to", there's nothing wrong with it, and replacing *"have been obliged"* by *"have had*" in the sentence above sounds fine to me.

For the question of whether the original sentence is grammatically correct, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be. It does sound very awkward to me.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is not grammatical.

Your interpretation is not correct.

Comment: This is a very short answer. More explanation would be helpful.